# im trying to transform using tfidf but it is giving error

Tags: pandas, nlp, tf-idf

I'm just trying to fit but it is giving this error. stemming is done

```
vectorizer_tf =TfidfVectorizer(df['Stemmed'],max_df=0.75,max_features=2000,lowercase=False, ngram_range=(1,2))
train_vec = vectorizer_tf.fit_transform(df['Description_no_sw'])
```

error  : The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

I'm just trying to fit but it is giving this error. stemming is done

Comment: Could you share the stack trace?

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1328     def __nonzero__(self):
   1329         raise ValueError(
-> 1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1331             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1332         )

Comment: What do `df['Stemmed']` and `df['Description_no_sw']` look like ?

Comment: Also you shouldn't pass a forst parameter to `TfidfVectorizer` [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html?highlight=tfidfvectorizer#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer)